# asp.net mvc session example

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

can someone give me an example or link to one of using a session in asp.net mvc?

Comment: I suppose it works just like in webforms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same as in WebForms:

Use the HttpContext.Current.Session object.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = "Jon";

string userName = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"];
```

Comment: You posted 10 seconds earlier! ^^

Comment: I have seen this comment: If ASP MVC is being used then it is preferable to not use the actual Session object from HttpContext.Current.Session but to use the new HttpSessionStateWrapper&HttpSessionStateBase from System.Web.Abstractions.dll. But I can't get it working.

Comment: There is one small section on sessions in Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0 book (written by the authors of the framework) and they make use of standard ASP.NET Sessions as shown above.

Comment: Thats enough for me then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With [MVC Future](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) library it can be done much simpler

Add one line in `Global.asax.cs` in `Application_Start()` method

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new SessionValueProviderFactory());
```

Then you can access session in controller by

```
$Session["YourName"] = "some value";
```

or in View by

```
@Session["YourName"]
```

[here is article](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/03/03/asp-net-mvc-release-candidate-2-i-declare-myself-to-be-declarative.aspx) how to add library to you project